# Как добавить фильтр в таблицу (JTable)?

Tags: java, swing

Есть классы `Person.java`, `PersonJFrame.java` и `PersonTable.java`.

Все три класса занимаются одной задачей - парсят *.txt*-файл и создают таблицу из файла.

Как сделать фильтр для данной таблицы?

Есть пример с массивом, но с `Array`  я так и не смог разобраться.

Исходники:

```
package table;

public class Person {
  private String number;
  private String date;
  private String human;
  private String rooms;
  private String plosh;
  private String summa;
  private String price;
  private String realprice;
  private String autoinkrement;
  private String comment;

  public Person(String autoinkrement, String number, String date, String rooms, String human, String plosh, String summa, String price, String realprice, String comment) {

      this.autoinkrement = autoinkrement;
      this.number = number;
      this.date = date;
      this.human = human;
      this.rooms = rooms;
      this.plosh = plosh;
      this.summa = summa;
      this.price = price;
      this.realprice = realprice;
      this.comment = comment;
  }

  public String getAutoinkrement() {
      return this.autoinkrement;
  }

  public void setAutoinkrement(String autoinkrement) {
      this.autoinkrement = autoinkrement;
  }

  public String getNumber() {
      return this.number;
  }

  public void setNumber(String number) {
      this.number = number;
  }

  public String getDate() {
      return this.date;
  }

  public void setDate(String date) {
      this.date = date;
  }

  public String getHuman() {
      return this.human;
  }

  public void setHuman(String human) {
      this.human = human;
  }

  public String getRooms() {
      return this.rooms;
  }

  public void setRooms(String rooms) {
      this.rooms = rooms;
  }

  public String getPlosh() {
      return this.plosh;
  }

  public void setPlosh(String plosh) {
      this.plosh = plosh;
  }

  public String getSumma() {
      return this.summa;
  }

  public void setSumma(String summa) {
      this.summa = summa;
  }

  public String getPrice() {
      return this.price;
  }

  public void setPrice(String price) {
      this.price = price;
  }

  public String getRealprice() {
      return this.realprice;
  }

  public void setRealprice(String realprice) {
      this.realprice = realprice;
  }

  public String getComment() {
      return this.comment;
  }

  public void setComment(String comment) {
      this.comment = comment;
  }
}
```

`PersonJFrame.java`:

```
package table;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTable;
import table.Person;
import table.PersonTable;

public class PersonJFrame extends JFrame {
    private JScrollPane scrollPane;
    private JTable table;

    public PersonJFrame(String title) throws FileNotFoundException, IOException {
        super(title);
        this.setSize(600, 400);
        this.setVisible(true);
        this.table = new JTable();
        this.scrollPane = new JScrollPane(this.table);
        this.getContentPane().add(this.scrollPane, "Center");
        ArrayList personlist = FileLoading();
        this.table.setModel(new PersonTable(personlist));
    }

    public static ArrayList<Person> FileLoading() throws FileNotFoundException, IOException {
        ArrayList personinfo = new ArrayList();
        BufferedReader file = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("src/Kurortniy.txt"));
        String line = file.readLine();
        String[] temp = line.split(" ");

        while((line = file.readLine()) != null) {
            temp = line.split(" ");
            personinfo.add(new Person(temp[0], temp[1], temp[2], temp[3], temp[5], temp[4], temp[6], temp[7], temp[8], temp[9]));
        }


        return personinfo;
    }

 }
```

и класс `PersonTable.java`:

```
package table;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import javax.swing.table.AbstractTableModel;
import table.Person;

public class PersonTable extends AbstractTableModel {
    private final String[] headers = new String[]{"AI", "№ Квартиры", "Дата", "Комнаты", "Площадь", "Ф.И.О", "Сумма", "Цена за Кв/м", "Рыночная цена", "Комментарий"};
    private final ArrayList<Person> person;

    public PersonTable(ArrayList<Person> person) {
        this.person = person;
    }

    public int getColumnCount() {
        return this.headers.length;
    }

    public String getColumnName(int header) {
        return this.headers[header];
    }

    public int getRowCount() {
        return this.person.size();
    }

    public Object getValueAt(int row, int column) {
        Person p = (Person)this.person.get(row);
        return column == 0?p.getAutoinkrement():(column == 1?p.getNumber():(column == 2?p.getDate():(column == 3?p.getRooms():(column == 5?p.getHuman():(column == 4?p.getPlosh():(column == 6?p.getSumma():(column == 7?p.getPrice():(column == 8?p.getRealprice():(column == 9?p.getComment():null)))))))));
    }
}
```

А хочу вот так, только с Array и чтением из txt.

```
package components;
public class TableFilterDemo extends JPanel {
    private boolean DEBUG = false;
    private JTable table;
    private JTextField filterText;
    private JTextField statusText;
    private TableRowSorter<MyTableModel> sorter;

    public TableFilterDemo() {
        super();
        setLayout(new BoxLayout(this, BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));

        //Create a table with a sorter.
        MyTableModel model = new MyTableModel();
        sorter = new TableRowSorter<MyTableModel>(model);
        table = new JTable(model);
        table.setRowSorter(sorter);
        table.setPreferredScrollableViewportSize(new Dimension(500, 70));
        table.setFillsViewportHeight(true);

        //For the purposes of this example, better to have a single
        //selection.
        table.setSelectionMode(ListSelectionModel.SINGLE_SELECTION);

        //When selection changes, provide user with row numbers for
        //both view and model.
        table.getSelectionModel().addListSelectionListener(
                new ListSelectionListener() {
                    public void valueChanged(ListSelectionEvent event) {
                        int viewRow = table.getSelectedRow();
                        if (viewRow < 0) {
                            //Selection got filtered away.
                            statusText.setText("");
                        } else {
                            int modelRow = 
                                table.convertRowIndexToModel(viewRow);
                            statusText.setText(
                                String.format("Selected Row in view: %d. " +
                                    "Selected Row in model: %d.", 
                                    viewRow, modelRow));
                        }
                    }
                }
        );


        //Create the scroll pane and add the table to it.
        JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(table);

        //Add the scroll pane to this panel.
        add(scrollPane);

        //Create a separate form for filterText and statusText
        JPanel form = new JPanel(new SpringLayout());
        JLabel l1 = new JLabel("Filter Text:", SwingConstants.TRAILING);
        form.add(l1);
        filterText = new JTextField();
        //Whenever filterText changes, invoke newFilter.
        filterText.getDocument().addDocumentListener(
                new DocumentListener() {
                    public void changedUpdate(DocumentEvent e) {
                        newFilter();
                    }
                    public void insertUpdate(DocumentEvent e) {
                        newFilter();
                    }
                    public void removeUpdate(DocumentEvent e) {
                        newFilter();
                    }
                });
        l1.setLabelFor(filterText);
        form.add(filterText);
        JLabel l2 = new JLabel("Status:", SwingConstants.TRAILING);
        form.add(l2);
        statusText = new JTextField();
        l2.setLabelFor(statusText);
        form.add(statusText);
        SpringUtilities.makeCompactGrid(form, 2, 2, 6, 6, 6, 6);
        add(form);
    }

    /** 
     * Update the row filter regular expression from the expression in
     * the text box.
     */
    private void newFilter() {
        RowFilter<MyTableModel, Object> rf = null;
        //If current expression doesn't parse, don't update.
        try {
            rf = RowFilter.regexFilter(filterText.getText(), 0);
        } catch (java.util.regex.PatternSyntaxException e) {
            return;
        }
        sorter.setRowFilter(rf);
    }




    class MyTableModel extends AbstractTableModel {
        private String[] columnNames = {"First Name",
                                        "Last Name",
                                        "Sport",
                                        "# of Years",
                                        "Vegetarian"};
        private Object[][] data = {
        {"Kathy", "Smith",
         "Snowboarding", new Integer(5), new Boolean(false)},
        {"John", "Doe",
         "Rowing", new Integer(3), new Boolean(true)},
        {"Sue", "Black",
         "Knitting", new Integer(2), new Boolean(false)},
        {"Jane", "White",
         "Speed reading", new Integer(20), new Boolean(true)},
        {"Joe", "Brown",
         "Pool", new Integer(10), new Boolean(false)}
        };

        public int getColumnCount() {
            return columnNames.length;
        }

        public int getRowCount() {
            return data.length;
        }

        public String getColumnName(int col) {
            return columnNames[col];
        }

        public Object getValueAt(int row, int col) {
            return data[row][col];
        }

        /*
         * JTable uses this method to determine the default renderer/
         * editor for each cell.  If we didn't implement this method,
         * then the last column would contain text ("true"/"false"),
         * rather than a check box.
         */
        public Class getColumnClass(int c) {
            return getValueAt(0, c).getClass();
        }

        /*
         * Don't need to implement this method unless your table's
         * editable.
         */
        public boolean isCellEditable(int row, int col) {
            //Note that the data/cell address is constant,
            //no matter where the cell appears onscreen.
            if (col < 2) {
                return false;
            } else {
                return true;
            }
        }

        /*
         * Don't need to implement this method unless your table's
         * data can change.
         */
        public void setValueAt(Object value, int row, int col) {
            if (DEBUG) {
                System.out.println("Setting value at " + row + "," + col
                                   + " to " + value
                                   + " (an instance of "
                                   + value.getClass() + ")");
            }

            data[row][col] = value;
            fireTableCellUpdated(row, col);

            if (DEBUG) {
                System.out.println("New value of data:");
                printDebugData();
            }
        }

        private void printDebugData() {
            int numRows = getRowCount();
            int numCols = getColumnCount();

            for (int i=0; i < numRows; i++) {
                System.out.print("    row " + i + ":");
                for (int j=0; j < numCols; j++) {
                    System.out.print("  " + data[i][j]);
                }
                System.out.println();
            }
            System.out.println("--------------------------");
        }
    }

    /**
     * Create the GUI and show it.  For thread safety,
     * this method should be invoked from the
     * event-dispatching thread.
     */
    private static void createAndShowGUI() {
        //Create and set up the window.
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("TableFilterDemo");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        //Create and set up the content pane.
        TableFilterDemo newContentPane = new TableFilterDemo();
        newContentPane.setOpaque(true); //content panes must be opaque
        frame.setContentPane(newContentPane);

        //Display the window.
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        //Schedule a job for the event-dispatching thread:
        //creating and showing this application's GUI.
        javax.swing.SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                createAndShowGUI();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Вам стоит ознакомиться с рекомендациями о том, [как создать краткий, завершенный и достоверный пример](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)